# ComplexNetworkSim wasn't installed correctly? Or SimPy?

Tags: python, simpy, complex-networks

I tried to install ComplexNetworkSim. I followed the instructions that appear here: 
https://pythonhosted.org/ComplexNetworkSim/installation.html

As recommended, I used setuptools to install NetworkX and SimPy (which are prerequisites for ComplexNetworkSim).

However, when I'm trying to use the package in PyCharm, based on [this example](https://pythonhosted.org/ComplexNetworkSim/start.html#start):

```
from ComplexNetworkSim import NetworkAgent, Sim
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Natan/PycharmProjects/final_project_Lev/solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ComplexNetworkSim import NetworkAgent, Sim
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ComplexNetworkSim\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\ComplexNetworkSim\agents.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named SimPy
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't install `simpy` correctly.  Maybe it's not in your path.  Manual installations can be hard to debug.  Unless there is some reason not to, you should use `pip` (or another package manager) for installations.  Using pip you simply run:

```
$ pip install complexnetworksim
```

which leads to the output:

```
Collecting complexnetworksim
  Downloading ComplexNetworkSim-0.1.2.zip (3.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.3MB 715kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from complexnetworksim)
Collecting simpy (from complexnetworksim)
  Downloading simpy-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.1.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkx->complexnetworksim)
Building wheels for collected packages: complexnetworksim
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for complexnetworksim ... done
  Stored in directory: ~/.cache/pip/wheels/32/c9/ea/71d1702cf26c7a4d0408ff02fbeadb1ca2e30e28511af11068
Successfully built complexnetworksim
Installing collected packages: simpy, complexnetworksim
Successfully installed complexnetworksim-0.1.2 simpy-3.0.10
```

But that loads an out-of-date version and still might cause problems.  You may want to follow the developer's advice on https://github.com/jschaul/ComplexNetworkSim and use the newer package `nxsim`.

Comment: It seems that when I install SimPy, the package is saved as "simpy" rather than "SimPy".
It causes problems because importing of modules is case sensitive. 
If I change the name of the package to SimPy, it is found, but then all other places that call simpy fail.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As mmdanziger suggested, I decided to give up on complexNetworkSim. 
Instead, I installed nxsim for Python 3 and it works just fine.